# Exe4j creates apps that i can no longer pin on taskbar Windows 11

Tags: java, exe4j

Moved to Windows 11, previously in windows 10 I would pin several exes built by exe4j to the taskbar, by running the exe and then pinning when it appears on task bar.

On windows 11 they do not appear as exes on task bar when run, they all appear under a command prompt icon. Pinning it will simply pin windows command prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on Windows 11. Please try with the demo/gui/hello.exe4j sample project.

Comment: Hi, tried that, and the same for the cli hellow world exe4j exe, I am still on exe4j 6 but cannot see anythig in the release notes that would suggest anything OS related has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, if you start a powershell command window, mine shows as a tabbed window with the usual command prompt, I believe this is the "Windows Terminal" app rather than a standard command prompt most are used to, hit the down arrow at the end of the tabs, and select settings, there is a setting called "Default terminal application", mine was set to "Let Windows decide". I changed this to "Windows Console Host" and my exe4j exes now are available again on the taskbar as separate apps and can be pinned.

[Command prompt settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnOgx.png)